# Determining Primary Key columns via GetSchema

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, ado.net

Is there a way to determine whether a column is a primary key using the ADO.NET `GetSchema` method?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public IEnumerable<DbColumnInfo> GetColumns(string providerName, string connectionString, string tableName)
{
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
    using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;

        var columns = connection.GetSchema("Columns", tableName.Split('.'));
        foreach (DataRow row in columns.Rows)
        {
            yield return new DbColumnInfo()
            {
                Name = row.Field<string>(3),
                OrdinalPosition = row.Field<short>(4),
                DataType = this.FormatDataType(row),
                IsNullable = string.Equals(row.Field<string>(6), "yes", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
                IsPrimaryKey = // ... ?
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use GetSchema or are you open to using a regular query? I used Sql Profiler to trace what Sql Management Studio does when you expand the columns node of a table and adapted a query from that. When I get into work tomorrow, I'll post it if it's any use to you.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I know this is a year old, but I'm curious if you have a decent implementation of `FormatDataType` you're willing to share in a gist or something, or for that matter the view and/or other provider code you ended up coming up with?

Comment: @qes In the end I settled on using a SQL query rather than ADO to get the info I needed. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't determine with connection.GetSchema() ...

But as a workaround you can try the dataadapter, if it is suitable for you:

```
    var da = factory.CreateDataAdapter();
    command.CommandText = "select * from Employees";
    da.SelectCommand = command;
    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

    var dtab = new DataTable();
    da.FillSchema(dtab, SchemaType.Source);

    foreach (DataColumn col in dtab.Columns)
    {
        string name = col.ColumnName;
        bool isNull = col.AllowDBNull;
        bool isPrimary = dtab.PrimaryKey.Contains(col);
    }
```

Comment: I've thought about that but I also need to reliably retrieve the underlying SQL datatype of the column (e.g. `NVARCHAR(255)` as apposed to `System.String`). AFAIK `GetSchema("Columns")` is the only way to do that. I'm really hoping to avoid making 2 calls to the database.

Comment: I don't know that, thanks. Maybe a select from system views? But that will be specific for a given provider ...

Comment: I ended up going with a solution which uses system views for the SQL server provider and combination of `FillSchema` and `GetSchema` for more generic providers. It's not pretty, but it works reasonably well on the providers I need it to. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Since *qes* asked, what I'm currently using (after several versions refactoring the code away since *Laszlo* provided his working solution) was not as elegant as I had hoped for, but it was more efficient and satisfied my needs. Basically I provide a `DbInfoProvider` class which is designed to produce `DbTableInfo` and `DbColumnInfo` for a given provider. The `SqlDbInfoProvider` uses this to get column information for SQL Server only:

```
public IEnumerable<DbColumnInfo> GetColumns(string connectionString, DbTableInfo table)
{
    DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(this.providerName);
    using (DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = ColumnInfoQuery;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        var tableSchema = factory.CreateParameter();
        tableSchema.ParameterName = "@tableSchema";
        tableSchema.DbType = DbType.String;
        tableSchema.Value = table.Schema;
        command.Parameters.Add(tableSchema);
        var tableName = factory.CreateParameter();
        tableName.ParameterName = "@tableName";
        tableName.DbType = DbType.String;
        tableName.Value = table.Name;
        command.Parameters.Add(tableName);

        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                yield return new DbColumnInfo()
                {
                    Name = reader.GetString(0),
                    OrdinalPosition = reader.GetInt32(1),
                    DataType = reader.GetString(2),
                    IsNullable = reader.GetBoolean(3),
                    IsPrimaryKey = reader.GetBoolean(4),
                    IsForeignKey = reader.GetBoolean(5),
                    IsUnique = reader.GetBoolean(6),
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `ColumnInfoQuery` is a static string like this:

```sql
SELECT c.[column_name]
     , CAST(c.[ordinal_position] AS int) [ordinal_position]
     , CASE WHEN c.[data_type] IN ( 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'smalldatetime', 'int', 'bigint', 'smallint', 'tinyint', 'real', 'money', 'smallmoney', 'image', 'text', 'ntext' )  THEN c.[data_type]
            WHEN c.[character_maximum_length] IS NOT NULL
            THEN c.[data_type] + '(' + CAST(c.[character_maximum_length] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ')'
            WHEN c.[datetime_precision] IS NOT NULL 
            THEN c.[data_type] + '(' + CAST(c.[datetime_precision] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ')'
            WHEN c.[numeric_scale] IS NOT NULL 
            THEN c.[data_type] + '(' + CAST(c.[numeric_precision] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ',' + CAST(c.[numeric_scale] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ')'
            WHEN c.[numeric_precision] IS NOT NULL 
            THEN c.[data_type] + '(' + CAST(c.[numeric_precision] AS VARCHAR(30)) + ')'
            ELSE c.[data_type]
       END [data_type]
     , CAST(MAX(CASE c.[is_nullable] WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit) [is_nullable]
     , CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN pk.[constraint_type] = 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit) [is_primary_key]
     , CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN pk.[constraint_type] = 'FOREIGN KEY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit) [is_foreign_key]
     , CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN pk.[constraint_type] = 'FOREIGN KEY' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS bit) [is_unique]
FROM information_schema.columns c
LEFT JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu 
        ON c.[column_name] = ccu.[column_name] 
        AND c.[table_name] = ccu.[table_name] 
        AND c.[table_schema] = ccu.[table_schema]
        AND c.[table_catalog] = ccu.[table_catalog]
LEFT JOIN information_schema.table_constraints pk 
        ON pk.[constraint_name] = ccu.[constraint_name]
        AND pk.[table_name] = ccu.[table_name] 
        AND pk.[constraint_schema] = ccu.[table_schema]
        AND pk.[constraint_catalog] = ccu.[table_catalog]
        AND pk.[constraint_type] IN ( 'PRIMARY KEY', 'FOREIGN KEY', 'UNIQUE' )
WHERE c.[table_schema] = @tableSchema
        AND c.[table_name] = @tableName
GROUP BY c.[table_schema], c.[table_name], c.[column_name], c.[ordinal_position]
       , c.[data_type], c.[character_maximum_length], c.[datetime_precision]
       , c.[numeric_precision], c.[numeric_scale], c.[is_nullable]
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up finding https://dbschemareader.codeplex.com/ which got me a long ways but still doesn't return everything accurately. Writing some integration tests for a migration helper lib https://bitbucket.org/qes/easymigrator

Answer (score 2):

Yes,
you can determine which columns are primary keys by requesting the schema for the Indexes. Then search the indexes for the specific colum / table

```
DataTable indexes = conn.GetSchema("Indexes");
List<string> PrimaryKeys = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow row in indexes.Rows)
  if (Convert.ToBoolean(row["PRIMARY_KEY"]))
    PrimaryKeys.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"] + "." + row["COLUMN_NAME"]);
```

the PrimaryKeys will contain the list of primary keys in the database. simply check if your [table].[column] is in this list.

Comment: I don't think this works against every server version of Sql Server, vr 2008 doesn't return a 'PRIMARY_KEY' column

Comment: I can't get this to work on SQL server 2016 either... :/

Answer (score 0):

This works on SQLITE and possibly other databases:-

```
            string[] restrictions = new string[] { null, null,   strTable };
            DataTable tableInfo = Connection.GetSchema("IndexColumns", restrictions);

            if (tableInfo == null)
                throw new Exception("TableInfo null Error");

            foreach (DataRow test in tableInfo.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(test["column_name"]);             
            }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Much easier then the accepted answer and the `MS SQL Server` also supports this: [SQL Server Schema Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms254969.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

At least with the Oracle ODP.Net provider there is a "PrimaryKeys" option for GetSchema().  I would suggest you use GetSchema() with no parameters to see what other calls are defined for your implementation.  This code retrieves the GetSchema() meta definitions that describes the other implemented GetSchema() calls for the Oracle provider.

```
    private void GetSchemaMetaInfo(DbConnection connection)
    {
        var metaDataCollections = connection.GetSchema("MetaDataCollections");
        var dataSourceInformation = connection.GetSchema("DataSourceInformation");
        var dataTypes = connection.GetSchema("DataTypes");
        var restrictions = connection.GetSchema("Restrictions");
        var reservedWords = connection.GetSchema("ReservedWords");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the PrimaryKeys collection to determine the primary key
for your specific table and then to retrieve the corresponding index name and then get the columns that constitute the index and primary key from the IndexColumns collection.

```
String pkIndxNm = null;
List<String> lstPkColNms = new List<String>();

DataTable dt = dbConn.GetSchema("PrimaryKeys", new[] { owner, tblNm });
if (dt.Rows.Count == 1) {
    DataRow pkRow = dt.Rows[0];
    pkIndxNm = pkRow["INDEX_NAME"] as String;

    // Now use the IndexColumns collection to pick up the names of the 
    // columns which constitute the primary key.
    //
    dt = dbConn.GetSchema("IndexColumns", new[] { owner, pkIndxNm });
    foreach (DataRow icRow in dt.Rows) {
        String colNm = icRow["COLUMN_NAME"] as String;
        lstPkColNms.Add(colNm);
    }
}
```

This worked against an Oracle database using the System.Data.Common.DbConnection
class with an underlying System.Data.OracleClient connection.

For other databases you might need to examine the Restrictions collection for
what you can pass as arguments. The documentation for GetSchema restrictions 
seems pretty useless. I found that just dumping the DataTable of the
Restrictions collection is the best way to understand how each collection can
best be queried:

```
  DataTable dt = dbConn.GetSchema("Restrictions");
  AppLog.Log.Info("CollectionName | RestrictionName | ParameterName | " +
                  "RestrictionDefault | RestrictionNumber");
  AppLog.Log.Info(" ");
  foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows) {
      String s = r["CollectionName"] as String;
      s += " | " + r["RestrictionName"] as String;
      s += " | " + r["ParameterName"] as String;
      s += " | " + r["RestrictionDefault"] as String;
      s += " | " + r["RestrictionNumber"].ToString();
      AppLog.Log.Info(s);
  }
```

Here is what I got, and from that I knew to pass the owner and indexName in the 
1st and 2nd positions of the array to constrain it to the proper index.

Users | UserName | NAME | USERNAME | 1

Tables | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

Tables | Table | TABLENAME | TABLE_NAME | 2

Columns | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

Columns | Table | TABLENAME | TABLE_NAME | 2

Columns | Column | COLUMNNAME | COLUMN_NAME | 3

Views | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

Views | View | VIEWNAME | VIEW_NAME | 2

Synonyms | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

Synonyms | Synonym | SYNONYMNAME | SYNONYM_NAME | 2

Sequences | Owner | OWNER | SEQUENCE_OWNER | 1

Sequences | Sequence | SEQUENCE | SEQUENCE_NAME | 2

ProcedureParameters | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

ProcedureParameters | ObjectName | OBJECTNAME | OBJECT_NAME | 2

Functions | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

Functions | Name | NAME | OBJECT_NAME | 2

IndexColumns | Owner | OWNER | INDEX_OWNER | 1

IndexColumns | Name | NAME | INDEX_NAME | 2

IndexColumns | TableOwner | TABLEOWNER | TABLE_OWNER | 3

IndexColumns | TableName | TABLENAME | TABLE_NAME | 4

IndexColumns | Column | COLUMNNAME | COLUMN_NAME | 5

Indexes | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

Indexes | Name | NAME | INDEX_NAME | 2

Indexes | TableOwner | TABLEOWNER | TABLE_OWNER | 3

Indexes | TableName | TABLENAME | TABLE_NAME | 4

Packages | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

Packages | Name | PACKAGENAME | OBJECT_NAME | 2

PackageBodies | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

PackageBodies | Name | NAME | OBJECT_NAME | 2

Arguments | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

Arguments | PackageName | PACKAGENAME | PACKAGE_NAME | 2

Arguments | ObjectName | OBJECTNAME | OBJECT_NAME | 3

Arguments | ArgumentName | ARGUMENTNAME | ARGUMENT_NAME | 4

Procedures | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

Procedures | Name | NAME | OBJECT_NAME | 2

UniqueKeys | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

UniqueKeys | Table_Name | TABLENAME | TABLE_NAME | 2

UniqueKeys | Constraint_Name | CONSTRAINTNAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME | 3

PrimaryKeys | Owner | OWNER | OWNER | 1

PrimaryKeys | Table_Name | TABLENAME | TABLE_NAME | 2

PrimaryKeys | Constraint_Name | CONSTRAINTNAME | CONSTRAINT_NAME | 3

ForeignKeys | Foreign_Key_Owner | OWNER | FKCON.OWNER | 1

ForeignKeys | Foreign_Key_Table_Name | TABLENAME | FKCON.TABLE_NAME | 2

ForeignKeys | Foreign_Key_Constraint_Name | CONSTRAINTNAME | FKCON.CONSTRAINT_NAME | 3

ForeignKeyColumns | Owner | OWNER | FKCOLS.OWNER | 1

ForeignKeyColumns | Table_Name | TABLENAME | FKCOLS.TABLE_NAME | 2

ForeignKeyColumns | Constraint_Name | CONSTRAINTNAME | FKCOLS.CONSTRAINT_NAME | 3

Comment: As for MSSQL 2016 the "PrimaryKeys" collection (as you show in your answer) does not exist at all.  So I don't think this will work for MSSQL server.